# Returning a class reference from the static method of an abstract class

Tags: c#, static, abstract-class

I understand that an abstract class can't be instantiated. Also, we can not use new keyword inside of a static method.

I'm wondering that how does the static Create method of XMLReader returns the reference of its class in the following statement:

XmlReader xmlReader=XmlReader.Create()

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the new keyword inside a static method, though it depends what you're trying to instantiate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns an instance of a derived class. It does not construct an `XmlReader` directly.

```
abstract class A {
    public static A Create() { return new B(); }
}
class B : A {
}
```

This is the same basic idea, and you can tell that that's what it does by calling `GetType()` on `XmlReader.Create`'s result. It won't return `typeof(XmlReader)`.